# How to set the precise max number of concurrently running tasks per node in Hadoop 2.4.0 on Elastic MapReduce

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop-streaming, elastic-map-reduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

According to http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/apache-hadoop-yarn-avoiding-6-time-consuming-gotchas/, the formula for determining the number of concurrently running tasks per node is:

```
min (yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb / mapreduce.[map|reduce].memory.mb, 
     yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores / mapreduce.[map|reduce].cpu.vcores) .
```

However, on setting these parameters to (for a cluster of c3.2xlarges):

yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb = 14336

mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 2048

yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores = 8

mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores = 1,

I find I'm only getting up to 4 tasks running concurrently per node when the formula says 7 should be. What's the deal?

I'm running Hadoop 2.4.0 on AMI 3.1.0.

Comment: can you try with http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html                                                            use yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent / yarn.scheduler.capacity.<queue-path>.maximum-am-resource-percent

Comment: CapacityScheduler is for distributing cluster resources among several YARN-based applications while ensuring some minimum capacity for each -- think PBS for YARN. I'm looking for the Hadoop 2.x analogs to Hadoop 1.x's mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum and mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum; and before someone says "mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum and mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum," these do not work in MapReduce2 because it does away with the TackTracker and the concept of slots -- read the first gotcha from the Cloudera blog post.

Comment: My issue is that Cloudera's formula may work for CDH but doesn't appear to for Hadoop 2.4.0 on EMR.

Comment: if you check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/HadoopMemoryDefault_H2.html. it will show default configs for c3.2xlarge. May be this can help to find out if there is memory left to run more processes ( maps) .

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sandesh; that is a useful link. I have found empirically that the formula is more like:

min (2 / 3 * yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb / mapreduce.[map|reduce].memory.mb, 
     yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores / mapreduce.[map|reduce].cpu.vcores)

on EMR. I wonder if the pmem-to-vmem ratio participates somehow. I guess I could dive into the source to see, but it would be nice to hear from someone with Hadoop 2.x expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My empirical formula was incorrect. The formula provided by Cloudera is the correct one and appears to give the expected number of concurrently running tasks, at least on AMI 3.3.1.

Comment: Im not seeing a formula different on that page than what you have listed above.  Could you please include the formula that yields the 4 tasks you are seeing?  Further do you know if vcores can be set fractional for IO bound tasks?

Comment: Check the comments on the question; the empirical formula I'm referring to is from comment on Aug 8, '14. This is the incorrect formula, and the correct formula is the one from Cloudera.