# EMR hadoop (MRv2) cluster is maxed at 80% capacity. How to get remaining 20%?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, emr

I'm using Elastic MapReduce (Hadoop 2.0 with YARN) on AWS.

The configuration is the following:

```
10 x g2.2xlarge core instances with 15GB of RAM and 8 CPU cores
yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled=false 
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=2048
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=12288
mapreduce.map.memory.mb=3072
```

When running a job the scheduler shows that only 81.7% of the cluster is allocated:

```
Used Capacity:  81.7%
Absolute Used Capacity: 81.7%
Absolute Capacity:  100.0%
Absolute Max Capacity:  100.0%
Used Resources: 
Num Schedulable Applications:   1
Num Non-Schedulable Applications:   0
Num Containers:  25
Max Applications:   10000
Max Applications Per User:  10000
Max Schedulable Applications:   6
Max Schedulable Applications Per User:  6
Configured Capacity:    100.0%
Configured Max Capacity:    100.0%
Configured Minimum User Limit Percent:  100%
Configured User Limit Factor:   1.0
Active users:   hadoop
```

The scheduler assigns max 3 containers per node and the total number of containers is capped at 25.

**Why does it only allocate 25 containers?**

From the memory settings I would expect to see

```
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb(12288) / mapreduce.map.memory.mb(3072) = 4 containers per node
```

Thanks

P.S. this looks like a similar questions but it's not answered
[How concurrent # mappers and # reducers are calculated in Hadoop 2 + YARN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414748/how-concurrent-mappers-and-reducers-are-calculated-in-hadoop-2-yarn)

Comment: How are you setting yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled on AWS?  How did you dump the cluster utilization metrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working after going through [this tutorial](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html).

2 things were changed:

1. mapreduce.map.memory.mb had a typo
2. mapreduce.map.java.opts which is set too low by default

The final settings that worked for me were:

```
yarn.nodemanager.vmem-pmem-ratio=50
yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=12288
yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb=3057
yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb=6114
mapreduce.map.java.opts: -Xmx2751m
mapreduce.map.memory.mb: 3057
```

Now it fully allocates 4 containers per node.